# Remove track from playlist with soundcloud Python

Tags: python-2.7, soundcloud

I can't figure out how to remove a track from a playlist. My code deletes the entire playlist, and I'd like to only delete one song.

```
client.delete(playlist_uri, playlist={
'tracks':track.id
})
```

Docs are [here](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#me) and [here](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/#uploading).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the docs, you don't want to call `delete` on the actual `playlist` itself, but `PUT` to the `/playlist/[id]` endpoint and change its array of track objects.

First `GET` the tracks in the playlist:

```
playlist = client.get('/playlists/2050462')
```

Them, update the array by removing the track you no longer want, and `PUT` the new array to the playlist endpoint for that playlist id.

```
# first, remove track from playlist.tracks

client.put(playlist.uri, playlist={
    'tracks': newTracks # where newTracks is playlist.tracks from above with the specified track removed
})
```

Comment: I'm getting a `422 Client Error: Unprocessable Entity for URL:` and then the API link

Also, I'm using a list of track IDs for "newTracks". Is that what you mean? Or do I use the WHOLE playlist.tracks?

When I use the whole track info like you say, I get a `500 server Error: Internal Server Error for url:` and the api.

Comment: I just mean an array of track ids.  Hmm, weird that you're getting an internal server error.  I'll keep testing but hopefully someone from SoundCloud can also chime in.

Comment: Wait, is an array not a list?

Comment: Obviously not >.< Thanks this will probably work now.